# Saved Search Date Results By Specified String in User Notes

Tags: netsuite

I'm new to netsuite and I'm wondering if anyone has some insight about how to create a saved search for records using specified strings in user notes.

More specifically, say a user entered a note in a record on 8/28/2019 that said "things."

How do I return the date in the saved search when the user entered the string, "things"?

Edit: To clarify, I already have the search for records built out.  I just want another column to be able to sort them by the date the string was entered.

Comment: Sounds like you need to grab data from the system notes.  Just use a formula and grab the date when the field changed equals that notes field, and the value contains that string.  It will generate a new line for each time the fields shows up in the system notes.

Answer (score 1):

On the ***Criteria*** tab:

*Filter* = User Notes : Memo (scroll down to the join fields where the labels all end in '...' and select 'User Notes Fields...', then select Memo from the popup list).

*Operator* = 'contains'

*Value* = 'things' (without quotes).

On the ***Results*** tab:

*Field* = User Notes : Date

Be aware that if there are multiple user notes with your search string under a single record, this will result in multiple results returned for the one record.  You can work around this if desired by grouping the records by ID and setting an appropriate aggregating function for all the other fields that you want visible (for example, you can set the Summary Type for the User Notes : Date field to MIN or MAX, depending on whether you want to see the first or most recent date when that string was entered).

It will also mean you're filtering out any records where that string is *not* found.

Comment: Thanks for your post!  Appreciate the help!